# Orbbec Astra Camera. Unable to receive images. Missing configuration files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

So, I run `roslaunch astra_launch astra.launch` and use Rviz to test out my Orbbec Astra camera. The problem is that the launch application gives me these messages if I try to subscribe to a topic on Rviz:

```
[ WARN] [1498238437.855693874]: Camera calibration file /home/tbot1/.ros/camera_info/rgb_Astra_Orbbec.yaml not found. 
[ WARN] [1498238564.009640794]: Camera calibration file /home/tbot1/.ros/camera_info/depth_Astra_Orbbec.yaml not found.
```

I've looked around and I can't seem to find any configuration files similar to what it's asking for.
Can anybody help me? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264622/orbbec-astra-camera.-unable-to-receive-images.-missing-configuration-files./) by [HaleyCurr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30885/haleycurr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are not files that are part of the source or binary distribution, as they are unique to each camera: they contain calibration values for the *intrinsics* of your sensor.

To generate them, you'll have to calibrate the camera. See [wiki/openni_launch/Intrinsic calibration of the Kinect cameras](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration) for a tutorial (it doesn't completely apply though, according to [this](https://3dclub.orbbec3d.com/t/astra-pro-rgb-camera-calibration-file/761) post on the ORBBEC forum).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HaleyCurr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30885/haleycurr/) on 2017-06-27**:
Thank you! We're trying to calibrate it now!